# how to redirect to index page in multi login when password does not match

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php include('includes/config.php');

  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
$empid=$_POST["empid"];
$pass=$_POST["password"];
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT employee_id, fname,lname,empid,password, status, role FROM employee");

      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $db_eid=$row["employee_id"];
    $db_empid=$row["empid"];
    $db_pass=$row["password"];
    $db_status=$row["status"];
    $db_role=$row["role"];
    $db_fname=$row["fname"];
    $db_lname=$row["lname"];
    if($empid==$db_empid && $pass==$db_pass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["empid"]=$db_empid;
        $_SESSION["role"]=$db_role;
        $_SESSION["status"]=$db_status;
        $_SESSION["employee_id"]=$db_eid;
        $_SESSION['uname']=$row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];

              if($_SESSION["role"]=='admin' && $_SESSION["status"]>0){
            $_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['empid'];
                header("Location:admin/dashboard.php");         
        }
        elseif($_SESSION["role"]=='TL' && $_SESSION["status"]>0){
            $_SESSION['tlogin']=$_POST['empid'];
            header("Location:TL/dashboard.php");
        }
          elseif($_SESSION["role"]=='employee' && $_SESSION["status"]>0){
            $_SESSION['emplogin']=$_POST['empid'];
            header("Location:home.php");
           }

        }
            else{
               header("Location:index.php");
                       }    
                 }
            }
         else 
             {
            header("Location:index.php");
               }
                    ?>
```

it is working properly when username and password match but if we enter a wrong password it is showing a blank page. In the blank page place when I try to give header("Location:index.php"); it does not working. I want to redirect the index page when the password is wrong.

Comment: Why you are fetching all rows from DB and checking in while loop for password and empid? You can directly do it in where condition of your mysql Query?

Comment: Remove while loop and put simple if else condition. In if condition put your logic and in else redirect user to index page.

Comment: i want to login based on the role

Comment: can you please help out with that

Answer (score 1):

You didn't deal with the situation that there is no matching record in database.

After the SQL query and before the while loop, adding the following code:

```
    if(!$query){
        header("Location:index.php");
        die;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, how do i add alert message when login credentials didn't match for the same above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Please ignore syntax errors just use the logic as I have not tested the code but it should give you an Idea.

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $empid = $_POST["empid"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT employee_id, fname,lname,empid,password, status, role FROM employee where empid=" . $empid . " And password='" . $pass . "'");


    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $db_eid = $row["employee_id"];
        $db_empid = $row["empid"];
        $db_pass = $row["password"];
        $db_status = $row["status"];
        $db_role = $row["role"];
        $db_fname = $row["fname"];
        $db_lname = $row["lname"];
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["empid"] = $db_empid;
        $_SESSION["role"] = $db_role;
        $_SESSION["status"] = $db_status;
        $_SESSION["employee_id"] = $db_eid;
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'];

        if ($_SESSION["role"] == 'admin' && $_SESSION["status"] > 0) {
            $_SESSION['alogin'] = $_POST['empid'];
            header("Location: admin/dashboard.php");
            die();
        } elseif ($_SESSION["role"] == 'TL' && $_SESSION["status"] > 0) {
            $_SESSION['tlogin'] = $_POST['empid'];
            header("Location: TL/dashboard.php");
            die();
        } elseif ($_SESSION["role"] == 'employee' && $_SESSION["status"] > 0) {
            $_SESSION['emplogin'] = $_POST['empid'];
            header("Location: home.php");
            die();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Regards.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, how do i add alert message when login credentials didn't match for the same above code.

Comment: You can set the error message in session and in your respective page after redirection check if error message is set in session and if it is set just show the error message on that page. Please mark the answer approved if it helped. Thanks. @VaraprasadReddy